# Problem w/ eventlistener function in my code

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my code not working and I don't know why. I have several options in my `html` as checkboxes and with a click on a button, I want the document.querySelector to get all the checkboxes that are checked and put them in an array (here called selection). This works but furthermore, I want then a for-loop to push all the names of the Elements in the selection array into the list array, but it is not doing that. If I use the console afterward and put in the exact same code from the loop, it works just fine, so there seems to be a problem within the eventListener and I don't know what is wrong.
Thank you in advance for your help!

```js
    const randButton = document.getElementById('GenSet');
    let selection;
    let list = [];
    randButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      selection = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
      for(let i = 0; i < selection.lenght; i++) {
        list.push(selection[i].name);
    
    }
    console.log(list);
    });
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible scenario.

Comment: `selection.length` instead of `selection.lenght` - a simple typo. (`selection.lenght` is undefined, but it is coerced to 0; your `for` loop has 0 iterations.)